# Распнут или разопнут (от распять) — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, спряжение

*И надо небом рискнуть,

И, может быть, невпопад

Еще не раз нас **распнут**

И скажут потом: распад.*
[**И. Бродский.** Стихи под эпиграфом](http://nata-koenig.narod.ru/stihi/brodsky.html) (1958)

*Да, следовало выбираться отсюда и начинать все заново. Опять мучиться, голодать, терпеть страх и стужу. Бороться. Что следовало бороться, в этом он не испытывал сомнений. Если они захватят, истребят, **разопнут** на кресте народ – не останется ничего. Ни прошлого, ни будущего. Значит, бороться за будущее.*
[**В. Быков.** Стужа](https://books.google.ee/books?id=AeLMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT156&lpg=PT156&dq=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82,%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82,%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4&source=bl&ots=A5nDw3mYGb&sig=ACfU3U3kXkkN1Z5FXLXn_eIw4tTX3LHsOw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio8u27hrLgAhXQcJoKHXYmAyMQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%82%2C%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4&f=false) (1969)

Просмотрела несколько словарей, но так и не смогла решить: как предпочтительнее "на сегодня" — **распнут** или **разопнут**. Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Смею предположить, что в 21 веке предпочтительнее "[распнут](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK64m6nLLgAhVoysQBHXluBmQQpwUIIQ&biw=1533&bih=748&dpr=1)" -  нежели "[разопнут](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%22&tbas=0&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJwLSOnbLgAhVWwsQBHevCBsA4ChCnBQgh&biw=1533&bih=748&dpr=1)"